# want a function that when a date is entered in the upper part it will show the data of that date and if no date is entered it will show the total data

Tags: excel, function, formula, data-analysis

[image]
I want it to read the data from the date, and in the upper part, if a manual date is entered, it will show the data of that date.

I put the date =Today() in the Report Day & time section and manually entered the Project Start and Project End in the bottom section.

Comment: And that I want it to move forward by itself after completion in the Days Completed section and I don't have to do anything; And also in the remaining days section, the number will change automatically after the day has passed.

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)